# File SOQL query

Tags: soql, content, files, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I need to search for Partner Accounts that don't have a Partner Agreement attached in the Files section. To find that, I believe the best way is to get a list of all Files attached to the Accounts that match the criteria. I managed to get a list of Files ID, but that is a bit useless for my purpose, what I really need is to include the Title in the results. Is this possible?

Here is my query so far, but I get an error saying

> INVALID_FIELD:  SELECT ContentDocumentID, ContentDocumentLinks.Title
>   FROM ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:27 Didn't understand relationship
>   'ContentDocumentLinks' in field path.

```
SELECT ContentDocumentID, ContentDocumentLinks.Title 
FROM   ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE  LinkedEntityId IN
  (SELECT ID FROM Account 
  WHERE   Type = 'Active Partner (signed contract)' 
  OR      Type = '2-Tier Partner')
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to fetch document's Title? Did you try using this name 'ContentDocument.Title' instead of ContentDocumentLinks.Title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not Title on ContentDocumentLink, 
availible fields are [documented here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_ContentDocumentLink.htm)

You could instead query the LinkedEntity.Name or the ContentDocument.Title if that hepls:

```
SELECT ContentDocumentID, LinkedEntity.Name, ContentDocument.Title
FROM   ContentDocumentLink 
WHERE  LinkedEntityId IN
  (SELECT ID FROM Account 
  WHERE   Type = 'Active Partner (signed contract)' 
  OR      Type = '2-Tier Partner')
```